# Is shortening a get set possible?

Tags: c#

So I got this code;

```
    public bool Guest
    {
        get { return GetValue("guest", true); }
        set { SetValue("guest", value); }
    }
```

I am wondering if it would be possible to shorten that as I would like to keep the code very clean, I've tried some stuff

```
    public bool Guest => GetValue("guest", true)
```

But can't seem to get Set working that way, is there a way to clean up that code? Or is that not a thing?

Any reply is very much appreciated, thanks (:

Comment: Is there  reason you need to use GetValue and SetValue?

Comment: We can't really give you a good answer to this without knowing more about the class that this is contained in.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is with **C# 7** where you can use expression bodied getters/setters:

```
class Person
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }
}
```

or with your example:

```
public bool Guest
{
    get => GetValue("guest", true);
    set => SetValue("guest", value);
}
```

but even with your original solution if you can use **C# 6** it's a good idea to not use strings but the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) keyword so you'll get:

```
public bool Guest
{
    get => GetValue(nameof(Guest), true);
    set => SetValue(nameof(Guest), value);
}
```